# trying to center text in echo

Tags: php, css

im trying to set the text like this

[image]
i have tried with

- display flex,
- position absolute,
- flex-direction,
- float:left,

> and nothing working on the echo

```
<?php
$servers = array('30120' => 1, '30121' => 2, '30122' => 3);

foreach ($servers as $key => $value) {

    $server = json_decode(@file_get_contents("http://xxxxxxxxx:$key/players.json"), true);

    if ($server) {
        $players = count($server);
        $key = "<p style=color:green;>Online</p><p>$players/32";
    } else {
        $key = "<p style=color:red;>Offline</p>";
    }

    echo "<h3>Server $value:</h3>";
    echo $key;
    echo "<br>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Please give us more information about your HTML, maybe create a JSFiddle.
In the example you gave, you did not apply any formatting beside text color...
Maybe use a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your items in a container, see the container as a row and the "servers" within as horizontal columns.

```
$servers = array('30120' => 1, '30121' => 2, '30122' => 3);

echo "<div style=\"display:flex;text-align: center\">"; // the row
  foreach ($servers as $key => $value) {

    $server = json_decode(@file_get_contents("http://xxxxxxxxx:$key/players.json"), true);

    if ($server) {
        $players = count($server);
        $key = "<p style=color:green;>Online</p><p>$players/32";
    } else {
        $key = "<p style=color:red;>Offline</p>";
    }

    echo "<div>"; // column
    echo "<h3>Server $value:</h3>";
    echo $key;
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```